# MySql database connection syncing with C# to view specific table values

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, synchronization

I'm implementing an application on C# connected to a MySql database. Part of the application I'm showing data from MySql database **table1** in a multi-line textbox in every 2 minutes, using a timer. Right now, the code is running perfectly. But, in the **textbox1** which I'm using to show database **table1** row values, It's just clearing the retrieved data and get whole bunch of data from the table and shows in the textbox view. The problem is when the database gets larger (like thousands of rows) it'll clear and retrieve all the row data over and over again in every 2 minutes.

---

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
   MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
   MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = "Select * FROM database_name.table1";
   MySqlDataReader myReader;

   try
   {
      myConn.Open();
      myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

      textBox1.Text = string.Empty;  //Clearing the retrieved data

      //looping and gets every row value from table1
      while (myReader.Read())
      {
           if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
               textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

           for (int i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
               textBox1.Text += myReader[i].ToString() + "    ";
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
   myConn.Close();
}
```

---

There are two problems that I'm still struggling with:

> **01.)**   I want to get only the updated value from the data base.
>   **02.)**   How to stick to the bottom in the multi-line text box when it keep updating?

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: To get only update data you need some kind of datetime of the update event in the records of your table and check these values against the time of the last read. The second point is not clear. Do you want the last line of your textbox to be visible after the data reload?

Comment: And looking at the answer below there is another point of confusion. When you talk about _updated data_ do you refer only to new records or do you refer to new inserted record and old records updated in the two minutes delay between reloads?

Comment: @Steve In this code I'm referring both updated and old records in the 2 minutes delay. but, I want only to refer the newly updated record instead of getting whole table again.

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution for 01) is:

1) Store in a variable the last row id retrieved from table. (lastStoredID)

2) Change

```
command.CommandText = "Select * FROM database_name.table1";
```

to

```
command.CommandText = "Select * FROM database_name.table1 where id > " + lastStoredID ;
```

3) Remove line

```
textBox1.Text = string.Empty;  //Clearing the retrieved data
```

Update:
If he wants only new inserted rows the solution above may be the right one.
If he wants not only just inserted rows, but updated rows the solution above is not the right one.

Comment: The above code doesn't worked for me. It's not getting anything to display and there's no exception coming out. I stored the last row id into lastStoredID variable by invoking a query **SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1**

Comment: @UserPhalcon: You should set lastStoredID from the rows that you have already fetched. If you use a `int?` (as in a `Nullable<int>`) you can simply execute the first command (as in select all) if the `HasValue` property is false, and the second command when you have some data. When you've read a bunch of rows, use `data.Max(row=>row.Id)` or something to get the latest row.